# Generic include

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, generics

I have a generic class that has a Get method using Find to find an entity from the database. It is working but it is not including the other entities that are found in the object.

Example:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }
}
```

An entity that can be found in the retrieved object which for instance is named User a profile  entity can be found but it is null. I need it included when I return the object. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your mapping for Profile entity? It should have something like `HasRequired(profile => profile.User).WithOptional(user => user.Profile);`

Comment: Did you mark your navigation properties as `virtual`?

Comment: @Loetn it does work when I mark the properties as virtual. If you add an answer I ll mark it as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mark your navigation properties as `virtual`.

```
public class User 
{
    public int ChildID;
    public virtual Child ChildEntity;
}
```

The `virtual` keyword will mark your property so that it will be lazy loaded when accessed.

Answer (score 0):

The marked answer will work as long as you are ok with lazy loading of entities.

If you are wanting to eagerly load instead, an alternative would be to write a generic including function like such:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> Including(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] _includeProperties)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = m_context.Set<TEntity>();
    return _includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
}
```

which could be used to achieve something similar, the only issue if you have to know the related entities to load.  The usage is something like this:

```
myEntity returnedEntity = myEntityRepository
                        .Including(x => x.Child1, x => x.Child2)
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```